# cocos2d-x 3.0 - Create sprite by relative path

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How can I create a sprite with relative path? I mean I have several folder in `Resources` directory such as:

- sd
- hd
- ....

One of this directories is set as **the place where resources should be looked up** :

```
std::vector<std::string> resDirOrders;
 if (device is hd)
      resDirOrders.push_back("hd")
FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchResolutionsOrder(resDirOrders);
```

Now in each of above mentioned directories I have lots of other directories such as:

- intro_popup
- outro_popup
- main_menu
- top_bar
- ingame
- ....

In these directories I place the images. And the names of images can collide, as far as I can have `coin.png` in `main_menu`, in `top_bar` in `ingame` which are different images. Theretofore, I want to be able to create a sprite like this:

```
Sprite::create("ingame/coin.png");
Sprite::create("top_bar/coin.png");
```

But it does not work. It just does not find the file coin.png.

How I should solve this issue? I am on Windows with cocos2d-x 3.0, but it should be handled on iOS and Android too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folder structure must be like this :

```
Res/
----hd/
----sd/
----ingame/
    ----hd/
    ----sd/
----top_bar/
    ----hd/
    ----sd/
```

You should add the Res folder to the project, and make sure that "Create folder references for any added folders" is checked.

Set the search path and search resolution order:

```
Size screenSize = Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getFrameSize();

std::vector<std::string> resDirOrders;

std::vector<std::string> searchPaths = FileUtils::getInstance()->getSearchPaths();
searchPaths.insert(searchPaths.begin(), "Res");
FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);

if (screenSize.width > 1024) {
    resDirOrders.push_back("hd");
}
else{
    resDirOrders.push_back("sd");
}

FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchResolutionsOrder(resDirOrders);
```

Then you can create the sprite with `Sprite::create("ingame/coin.png");`

Comment: Thank you man. You have saved my life. In order to inderstand why this work please confirm that `setSearchResolutionsOrder` is a directory which is being inserted between the path of image right before the image name, isn't it?